# XCode 6 Tab Bar tabs greyed out

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

Anytime I add a tab bar controller to XCode the tab bar is greyed out and I can't see any of the tabs in the storyboard.  At runtime it displays fine.  I can't figure out why it is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Add an image to the Tab Bar Item** and you will see the normal view of the tab bar on the specific View Controller where you changed it. When every single Tab Bar Item got an image you will also see the normal appearance in your Tab Bar Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Setting an image for the **Tab Bar Items** and **restarting** xcode fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the assets folder (or wherever your image is kept), set 'Render as' to Original image

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If you have tabs for which images are not yet set you will not see tabs in main tab bar controller. I've also noticed some strange behaviours for first and last images sometimes appearing or disappearing. So if you only have two tabs you could encounter different observations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this was a bug in the XCode UI.  This has been fixed in later versions of XCode.

Comment: No, not yet. I'm using the latest version of Xcode (7.2.1) and is still an issue.