# Can't select tab bar items, greyed out tab bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbar

My nav bar is completely greyed out. [I've seen some solutions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927244/xcode-6-tab-bar-tabs-greyed-out) saying that you should simply add an image to the tab bar item. I can't even select a tab bar item...see screen below.

Any ideas? I'm running Xcode 7.2, using Swift with a BaaS (Parse). I've searched for hours/days and can't figure this one out...May sound like a dumb question, but every other example I search essentially shows a tab bar with items that you can select/edit within the interface builder. As I can't figure out how to select a tab bar item within the interface builder, I've essentially been stuck. Do I need to do this all programmatically (I know some people have preference here), or can it be done in interface builder?

I add them as has been mentioned (using a view controller relationship segue, images below), but after I add it, everything is still greyed out and I don't have any tab bar items. Any ideas?

[control-click action, using relationship segue under view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHGaY.png)
[everything is greyed out, no tab bar items available to edit or add images to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn7A1.png)

Comment: the example you linked to was only a problem in the storyboard, and everything was OK at runtime - are you having the same problem, or is it greyed out at runtime?

Comment: Do you have any segues from this controller? Your tabs only appears when you add the controllers (linked to the tab bars).

Comment: @Russell Its completely grey at runtime as well. It works, as in, I can select the 5 views I have linked to it, but they are all grey. Any ideas? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: And to answer the question from @Brduca I have linked them (fairly positive I did it right, command-click, connected the view controllers)

Comment: in the linked views - what have you defined for the Bar Item - Title / Image?

Comment: I haven't defined anything for them because I'm not sure how to select them. In the past I remember clicking the tab bar within the interface builder to edit the tab bar items, but I can't do that now (its all greyed out). Has that changed? Do I need to define the Title/Image after I select the linked view controller? Apologies if I'm making this about as clear as mud.

Comment: @skind, ok you have to command-click but it's not an ordinary segue, what option did you choose? You must choose "Relationship Segue" and "View Controller". If you use an ordinary segue no item will appear on the tab bar.

Comment: @Brduca, thanks for the help. That's exactly how I set it up actually, and I've still got the grey. When I get home today I'll see if I can screenshot/copy some more information if that'd help in getting to an answer. Thanks a ton for the support.

Comment: @Brduca just realized that the Tab Bar Item has to be added/adjusted on the table view. I had that embedded within a NavBarViewController, which was embedded inside the TabBarViewController. Rookie mistake. Well, I'm a rookie, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here we go. You have a Tab Bar created.

Drag a **View Controller** to your storyboard. Place it next to your **Tab Bar**.

Ctrl-click on the **Tab Bar** and drag it to the **View Controller**.

Select the option like the image below.

[image]
About this this you must see the item on your tab bar. Click on it and you'll be able to edit (choose an image, change the label...).

Hope that helps.