# I can not edit my tab bar on storyboard. How to deal with it?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I cannot edit tab bar item because it became grey on storyboard? What's wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399519/5657370 
According to the thread, you can see your tab bar item after adding images to each view controller connected with Tab Bar Controller. First, you need to select viewcontroller and click 'Show Document Outline' menu in Storyboard. Then, you can select bar item and set your images in 'Bar Item'-'Image' menu in the Attributes Inspector.